# Instantiate and use 2 or more JavaScript ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Using JavaScript ES6 I have several classes into which I want to separate the various concerns of my app. I have a main.js file in which I wish to instantiate the classes and then be able to reference and call methods across them.

My question is: What is the best/standard way to do this? My current approach is as follows;

In **main.js** I create an App class which instantiates two classes

```
import ClassOne from './ClassOne';
import ClassTwo from './ClassTwo';

export default class App {
    constructor () {
        this.one = new ClassOne(this);
        this.two = new ClassTwo(this);
    }
}
const app = new App();
```

Then in **ClassOne.js** I do something like this

```
export default class ClassOne {
    constructor (app) {
        this.app = app;
        this.app.two.callMethod();
    }
}
```

It certainly works, but does it look stoopid & is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. When `ClassOne`s constructor is called, the `App`  instance doesn't yet have the `app.two` property. One needs to be careful whenever circular dependencies creep up.

Comment: In order to determine "best", there must be some evaluation criteria. "look stoopid" isn't really a suitable criterion.

Comment: This *shouldn't* really work since `two` isn't instantiated yet by the time you're trying to use it. Explicit dependency injection is the way to go, i.e. pass an instance of `ClassTwo` to `ClassOne`, instead of an instance of `App`.

Comment: @deceze What if `ClassTwo` also needs to refer to the `ClassOne` instance? Yes, making it explicit will help to catch mistakes, but what is the standard design for circular dependencies (apart from global declarations)?

Comment: @Bergi Circular dependencies cannot by definition require each other in their respective *constructors*, so something's logically very wrong there to begin with. You can only treat such a dependency as optional and *set* it later on the already instantiated class. E.g.: `this.one.two = this.two;`.

Comment: Thanks & you're absolutely right - my approach did break down for the reasons you explain. The answer below seems to address the problem both conceptually and in practice.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having a setter in ClassOne and ClassTwo. That way only ClassOne and ClassTwo are dependent on each other, and not on an instance of App.

**ClassOne.js**

```
export default class ClassOne {
    setTwo (two) {
        this.two = two;
        this.two.callMethod();
    }
}
```

**ClassTwo.js**

```
export default class ClassTwo {
    setOne (one) {
        this.one = one;
        this.one.callMethod();
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
import ClassOne from './ClassOne';
import ClassTwo from './ClassTwo';

export default class App {
    constructor () {
        this.one = new ClassOne();
        this.two = new ClassTwo();

        this.one.setTwo(this.two);
        this.two.setOne(this.one);
    }
}

const app = new App();
```